# Why setText() function doesn't work?

Tags: java, settext

can u tell me why this code is not working? The app stops as soon as I click on Image(Imageview1). Debugger points to tv.setText(x);

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String x="You clicked on the image.";
            tv.setText(x);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Try to run your app not in debugger.

Comment: Why does the debugger stop at `tv.setText(x)`?  Is there a breakpoint there?  Does the debugger tell you why it stopped?  Was any message displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get your UI elements **after** inflating your layout, otherwise `findViewById` returns `null` and hence the NPE is thrown when you try to set the text on your `textView`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);                       /// I swap these two lines
    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);   ///
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```